# Populate dropdown data from paginated API response in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a dropdown in my angular page

```html
    <select id="location_country" formControlName="location_country" class="form-control">
           <option *ngFor ="let country of countriesList">{{country.name}} </option>
    </select>
```

Here, the `countriesList` is coming from a web API as a JSON response.
So, the API URL looks like below

```
https://apis-dev.xxx.com/cls/geonames-api/countries?max=100&offset=1
```

The API team is not providing all countries in a single request as there is a offset request parameter. If I need to see the next 100 countries I need to call the API again like

```
https://apis-dev.xxx.com/geonames-api/countries?max=100&offset=100
```

So, is there any way I can load all countries in the dropdown? For example lazy loading while scrolling dropdown values etc?

component.ts

```js
    public loadCountries() {
      this.geonamesService.getCountries().subscribe(data => {
        this.countriesList = data;    
      });
    }
```

service.ts

```js
    getCountries() {
        let url = this.configManagerService.countriesApiUrl;
        return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }
```

Sample JSON response from API

```json
        [
                {
                "id": 287316,
                "isoName": "Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands",
                "countryCode": "MP",
                "name": "Northern Mariana Islands",
                "cscId": 287316,
                "geoNamesId": 4041468
                },
                {
                "id": 287167,
                "isoName": "Kingdom of Norway",
                "countryCode": "NO",
                "name": "Norway",
                "cscId": 287167,
                "geoNamesId": 3144096
                },
                {
                "id": 287294,
                "isoName": "Sultanate of Oman",
                "countryCode": "OM",
                "name": "Oman",
                "cscId": 287294,
                "geoNamesId": 286963
                }
        ]
```

Please suggest if there is anything. Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to detect scrolling in a normal select, so if you want behaviour like that I suggest building a custom select. Otherwise you have to load all at once but that could potentially lead to performance issues, so it's up to you how you want to solve it. You could try the 3rd option in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51677397/4054974 but it seems more like a hack that could easily fail on some browsers and devices so I would personally not use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select2 which implements complete infrastructure for pagination. It does lazy loading while scrolling dropdown values exactly like your need.

To use select2 in an Angular project:
You need first to install [ng-select2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-select2) (please follow the instructions carefully).

Then you can follow this working example:

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Options } from 'select2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public options: Options;

  constructor() {
    this.options = {
      ajax: {
        // Replace with your api URL
        url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
          var query = {
            q: params.term,
            per_page: 3,
            page: params.page || 1
          }
    
          // Query parameters will be ?q=[term]&per_page=[per_page]&page=[page]
          return query;
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
          // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
          // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
          // scrolling can be used
          params.page = params.page || 1;

          return {
            results: data.items,
            pagination: {
              more: (params.page * 3) < data.total_count
            }
          };
        },
      },
      templateResult: this.formatRepo,
      templateSelection: this.formatRepoSelection
    }
  }

  formatRepo (repo) {
    if (repo.loading) {
      return repo.text;
    }
    var $container = $(
      "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__avatar'><img src='" + repo.owner.avatar_url + "' width='50' /></div>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
          "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'></div>" +
          "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'></div>" +
          "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
            "<div class='select2-result-repository__forks'><i class='fa fa-flash'></i> </div>" +
            "<div class='select2-result-repository__stargazers'><i class='fa fa-star'></i> </div>" +
            "<div class='select2-result-repository__watchers'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> </div>" +
          "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
      "</div>"
    );
  
    $container.find(".select2-result-repository__title").text(repo.full_name);
    $container.find(".select2-result-repository__description").text(repo.description);
    $container.find(".select2-result-repository__forks").append(repo.forks_count + " Forks");
    $container.find(".select2-result-repository__stargazers").append(repo.stargazers_count + " Stars");
    $container.find(".select2-result-repository__watchers").append(repo.watchers_count + " Watchers");
  
    return $container;
  }

  formatRepoSelection (repo) {
    return repo.full_name || repo.text;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<ng-select2 
    [width]="500"
    [options]="options"></ng-select2>
```

Comment: don't use jQuery, don't use out-of-date libraries, don't create html in a variable, don't.... Really Rami, avoid use any Angular library that use jQuery. remember that Angular and jQuery is a bad combination

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get recursive you can define in your service a new observable "getAllData"

```
  //see that I don't indicate the "offset"
  url='https://apis-dev.xxx.com/cls/geonames-api/countries?max=100&offset='

  //get countries from offset
  getCountries(offset:number)  
  {
     return this.httpClient.get(this.url+offset)
  }

  //get all countries
  getAllCountries(offset: number = 0, resultOld: any[] = []) {
    return this.getCountries(offset).pipe(
      switchMap(res => {
        offset = res.length > 0 ? offset + res.length : -1;
        return offset >= 0
          ? this.getAllCountries(offset, [...resultOld, ...res])
          : of(resultOld);
      })
    );
  }
```

You can use with pipe async

```
<option *ngFor="let countries of dataService.getAllCountries()|async">...</option>
```

Or in subscribe

```
   this.dataService.getAllCountries().subscribe(res=>{
              console.log(res)
   })
```

A "fool example" -I don't get the countries else a series of numbers- in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vg7vta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)